# As we are all adults here, how do I politely indicate that I need the toilet?

Tags: international-travel, local-customs, hygiene, english-language

I am from an area where people just say they need the loo to pee or poo.
In formal situations, when meeting just strangers, we are a bit less open and call it 'need the toilet' but I know that in other countries they are a lot less open about it.

Small children, at the potty training age, are quite open about what they do and such, but soon they learn the local 'polite' way to say things and it is frowned upon if they even mention the words again.
The words acceptable are likely very clear in the area but likely hard to use for those not brought up in the same culture.
I have heard words as 'nr 1' and 'nr 2' but also some that I could not even understand well enough to remember.

So as a foreign tourist, I know I should not use the words I would use at home, not even in the more polite translations into English.
But what is acceptable?

I get by with asking for the 'ladies' and looking a bit uneasy, but I know it will still be seen as impolite in some societies. In the past I have asked for the bathroom to be shown a bedroom, by the person I was asking not understanding the evation.

Can you tell me what to use and in what situation this is acceptable?
Location and social class might be needed to get a good picture.
To keep this from going too wide, I feel I restrict it to just English speaking countries but I would not mind learning English equivalents for what people use in other language areas.

Comment: Perhaps carry around a copy of this and pull it out when needed?  http://amzn.to/23jWXlD

Comment: Fun books but I fear not suitable for polite society of adults.

Comment: Do we need an [tag:all-adults-here] tag yet?

Comment: I have proposed a 'toilets' one in chat but was told the others there did not feel that need, so I let it go.

Comment: Now this might sound like a joke, but it is NOT.. in flights to the Indian subcontinent, people make a fist while raising the _little_ finger, that's the sign when they want to use the toilet. I never get it, I tried to ask, never got an answer for the reasons behind this gesture.

Comment: That reminds me of the habit in Dutch schools where kids stick up a hand with the pointer finger raised when they know the answer, but with that and the next finger when they need to use the toilet.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Why exactly do people need to signal that they want to use the toilet at all? Don't people on a plane just get up and go?

Comment: @ZachLipton simple workers, they ae confused, many been on a plane for the first time, I am serious that's what they do..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis They raise the little finger to mean number one,  popular slang if you want to take a pee. I have not seen they raise two fingers for the heavy job though.

Comment: Bonus points to what to say when a Emirates flight crew keeps everyone with the food tray two hours because they do not want to clean the toilets.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I believe that would be a meta tag, which is generally bad. Most in-jokes don't need a special tag.

Comment: @Willeke They flip off the back of the class when they have to use the bathroom? I thought the middle finger as an insult was kind of universal - perhaps not?

Comment: Just for completeness: The euphemism "comfort station" is polite, formal, and inoffensive. I have seen it used in signage in older National Parks of the U.S. However, the phrase is rarely used nowadays, sounds very unusual in oral conversation, and may not be understood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your looking for a universal way that fits all circumstances, your best bet is going to be to ask someone. Your going to be the guest of someone. Even in a store you have the employees to help. So find someone that looks like they know the place, or better yet, invited you, and quietly, discreetly, let them know what your looking for. Then listen to the words they use, and don't be afraid to use them too.

For example, ask the person who invited you to the dinner party, quietly, "I don't really know how to ask properly, but I need to pee." They will respond based on their culture. If your talking with just one person and your quite, then it will be hard for them to be offended.

If your not comfortable with that, then ask for the "Lavatory". It's not exactly correct, but almost every English native speaker will be able to know what your after without making a scene.

As another general rule, there is no reason to state why you need that room. Again if your talking to one person, and that person is your host, or guide, then your probably fine. If your speaking to a group or something, then I would, generally, avoid saying why.

After a few days in an area, your should get the hang of it. When in doubt, ask the service staff. There the least likely to be offended by a simple, quite, question.

Comment: +1, as it will work in most places. But I did ask for people to tell me for their area/social class and polite society, (so not at a friends house nor a black tie dinner.)

Comment: Well that's kind of the reason for this answer. At least here in the US, your going to to get a very different answer depending on rather your shopping at Wal-Mart, Lowes, Target or Sears. And that's just if you ask in a store. What about a business meeting, are people wearing T-Shirts, Polos, Sport coats, or full suites. Are you in an area that has a lot of foreigners (international areas near airports, or tourist areas?) It can even be as simple as are you in a part of town dominated by one race or another? Maybe even, is the social gathering  dominated by one gender or the other?

Answer (score 37):

In the United States, the more polite terms I hear are usually either *the restroom* or *the ladies' room*/*men's room* (always including *room*). *Washroom* sounds Canadian to me. British terminology (such as *loo*) may well be understood but would sound odd.

So, I might ask: "Where's the restroom?" If I already knew, I'd most likely excuse myself without explanation.

**BEWARE:** In the United States, using the word *toilet* to mean anything other than the actual porcelain fixture sounds shocking or rude. The difference between British and American English in this regard is quite pronounced. The first time I visited the UK, I was quite surprised to see signs which read "Toilet." You would never see such in the US.

Also, I've encountered people in the UK who don't understand the word *restroom,* which is usual in the US. So, even within English, there's significant variation from region to region.

P.S.: In the US, *bathroom* and *restroom* are synonyms. However, *bathroom* is more informal, and is more likely to be used in a house than in a public  building. *Restroom,* while more formal, is quite acceptable in all situations and is the best default choice if you're unsure which is the best option. That said, using *bathroom* in a formal situation would only be a minor gaffe.

Comment: The thing seems to be that even in English, there are cultural variations (maybe even in the same country) so that the word that is blunt enough to offend, and the word that is vague enough but still can be understood both differ. Even "toilet" once was an euphmism for "lavatory" http://www.dictionary.com/browse/toilet#source-etymon2

Comment: Bathroom in the UK means a room with a bath. There might not be a toilet.

Comment: @fr13d: And in the US, the only place we use *lavatory* is for planes and buses. David: In the US, baths are optional in bathrooms. All: Quite a lot of regional variation, isn't there?!

Comment: In the U.S., I say "where's the rest room?" if I don't know, or "the rest room's just down the hall, right?" if I do.  Then, I say "I'll be back in just a minute," or "I'll be back in a few minutes," as appropriate.  Substitute "washroom" or "lavatory" in Canada, "lav" or "WC" in England.  There is **no** word that is both well-understood and polite in both the U.S. and U.K.; forget Canada, Australia, or other places.  If I thought of it, I'd ask a cab driver "how would a fancy person here say he has to go piss?"  (The less-polite words *are* well-understood everywhere.)

Comment: I've always found "rest room" a really odd choice.  The last thing I want to do there is rest!  That said, I am of Anglo-Saxon stock so being direct is not impolite - simply efficient.  Where's the toilet is just fine anywhere in the United Kingdom and dominions.

Comment: What part of the US are you from? I've never thought that using toilet in this fashion is shocking or rude.

Comment: Keep in mind rude has a lot to do with the circles you run in. I would be offended if someone at dinner announced to the table that they "need to use the toilet".

Comment: @bob:I've lived in all of the west coast states, plus the Southwest, Texas, and NY State. I've visited nearly all of the rest. I've never heard an American use *toilet* in the way it's used in many other countries, nor have I ever seen a sign saying "Toilet" with an arrow pointing to the facilities. In addition, another answerer here described the word *toilet* as "crude," so I'm not alone in this. Have you, perhaps, been exposed to people from other countries for a really long time? I know that exposure to different varieties of English can make it hard to tell what's American and what isn't.

Comment: In the UK, if you ask for a bathroom, then unless people recognize the Americanism and make allowances, they will assume you want a bath. And if you ask for a restroom, then (unless people recognize...) they will assume you want a rest.

Comment: I've lived in the US all my life, minimal contact with foreigners. No one I've ever known would consider it even remotely rude or shocking if you said 'toilet' instead of 'restroom.' It's just not the way the word is generally used. In fact a synonym for toilet (commode) is used in exactly that way among older southerners. If it's 'crude', it's crude in the same way that saying 'trash can' instead of 'waste basket' is crude.

Comment: In the US military, we were taught to call it a "latrine". You dont "rest" in there, and in public, you aren't walking in there for a "bath" (or shower).

Comment: @ScottSeverance: I did live for several years, when younger, in Germany as a military brat. That has skewed my sense of usual American behaviors. I find it interesting that some people think of toilet as a rude word. I've lived the majority of my life in coastal VA and I've heard people use toilet, though not often.

Comment: @Oberst, Marines and Navy call it the head.

Comment: Growing up in Australia, I once was asked by an American friend, "Where is your (family member)?" to which I replied, "In the toilet." It seemed a perfectly normal thing to say in Australian usage, but the American looked kind of shocked -- he probably thought I was making a crude joke. In American English, the toilet is not a room but a porcelain device.

Comment: Before I became aware of the differences, if I'd heard that someone was in the toilet, I would have thought that for some reason they had decided to take a swim in the porcelain bowl. Splish splash.

Comment: "Toilet" actually means "soft cloth over dressing table" and "lavatory" means "washroom". They are themselves euphemisms. I've never understood why Americans get embarrassed about things that are utterly universal. Here in Australia, if someone supplies far too much information (probably for the entertainment value of discomfiting prissy people) we are likely to raise the bar and mock them: "Don't forget to take lots of photos" (if we say anything at all). No doubt it's cultural. In France body functions are ok but death not, in the US death is ok but body functions aren't.

Comment: @PeterWone: The meanings of words can vary from country to country. In the US, if you use the word "toilet" with the meaning you give, it's doubtful anyone will understand you correctly. Perhaps in a literary sense there's more flexibility in meaning, but in normal conversation, the term only means the porcelain fixture.

Answer (score 20):

This question has been asked twice on English SE, the second in a British English context:

- [“Toilet”, “lavatory” or “loo” for polite society](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37177)
- [Is there a formal way to say we want to go to the toilet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/148362) [closed]

Too summarize that, **loo** or a bit more polite **lavatory** would be perfectly fine **in the UK**, while bathroom can be slightly confusing. People are more direct and also WC and toilet are not deemed inappropriate.

Instead **in the U.S.** you will find **bathroom**, **washroom** or **restroom** appropriate choices, whereas toilet, lavatory and others are used in slightly different contexts and sound strange if used in your intended context. See [this excellent answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37210) for more details.

This being a basic need of mankind, you will be able to find [tons of synonyms](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/bathroom), some of them questionable.

If you want to extend your vocabulary, also [this blog post](http://blogs.transparent.com/english/toilet-talk-english-vocabulary-about-using-the-bathroom/) might be helpful. Unfortunately it does not distinguish much between British and American English.

Comment: How common/polite is the use of the word 'loo'? From my friends in England I never hear the word when in big company nor do they seem to approve of it. Most of my friends are from the southeren parts of England, Cambridge to Bristol and south of that line. But our group is spread a lot wider, up into Scotland.

Comment: Indeed I'm not a native speaker and have no personal experience regarding British English so this is purely from the sources quoted and to be taken with a grain of salt. An answer from a native speaker of British English would be very welcome here.

Comment: @Willeke It's reasonably common and not really impolite...but it is a working class word and perhaps a little bit quaint.  You won't hear it from an RP Oxbridge alumnus, but it's not unusual to hear it, for example, in a pub.  Younger and trendier types will probably prefer "the gents" to "the loo".

Comment: Canadian English favors 'washroom', which, while typically understood below the 49th parallel, is largely not used there.

Comment: @Willeke J is kind of right, but "the gents" is very definitely in a public space.  A restaurant or pub has a "gents" and a "ladies", as two separate toilets.  A house simply doesn't, so it would quite likely lead to jokes about "is my house a hotel now?"  As mts says, "loo" is informal - you'd use it with your family and friends but probably not at a job interview, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I have indeed heard *washroom* used in the US, but it's a very distinctly Midwestern thing (pronounced more like *warshroom*)... and I actually think it may be dying out (I've only heard people middle-aged and older say it).

Comment: @J..: Also "do you know where the facilities are?"

Comment: @Graham Yeah, definitely no gents at someone's house, haha!

Comment: Also, no "gents" in the U.S.  "Men's Room," yes.  Asking "where's the gents?" in the U.S. would get you blank stares in any room devoid of anglophiles.

Comment: As well as 'turrlet' (the Archie Bunker pronunciation of toilet, it's probably best to avoid slang terms. I remember many years ago getting a rather shocked reaction in the Southern US when I asked a gas station cashier where the 'can' was. Apparently it means something else there.

Comment: I'm a native Brit, and I have never heard *anyone* say "lavatory" or "WC" out loud. Don't use "bathroom", that's where the bath is, not (necessarily) the toilet. The "most" correct phrasing would be "Could you tell me where the toilets are please?" (formal), or "I'm just nipping to the loo" (informal)

Comment: @J: As an oxford alumnus raised in the home counties and with an accent I have been told is "posh" I can assure you that I say "loo" and in my experience isn't a particularly class divided thing (at least I am most definitely middle class and a lot of other people I know also say "loo"). I'm probably not upper class which might be what you were referring to so I may be more taking issue with your assumption of oxbridge being very posh than your actual assertion on the formality of "loo".

Answer (score 9):

If I am looking for the toilet in an establishment I usually ask for the bathroom or the men's/women's room. My understanding is that the term *bathroom* is perceived as less crude than the word *toilet* hence why I don't user the latter.

If I am at a formal event, such as a black tie dinner, I usually just say "excuse me" and then stand up and leave. No need for details in this case.

Comment: +1. Bathroom sounds more polite. I once had a totally confused restaurant worker though. They did not have shower facilities, so I always  keep "toilet" at the tip of my tongue.

Comment: Bathroom is normal in the US. It might not be so common elsewhere.

Comment: "Bathroom" is *extremely* U.S.-specific.  Most non-American English speakers would have no idea what you meant.

Comment: Most British English speakers *understand* "basic American English", even if they don't habitually speak it. I expect the same would be true for any English speakers who regularly watch American TV and movies.

Answer (score 8):

The politest thing to do is to not draw attention to the fact that you need the toilet.

Don't indicate to all and sundry that you need the toilet.

If you need to know where the toilet is, ask where is the toilet/restroom/bathroom/lavatory, please?

If you are desperate to go during a meeting or conversation, quietly excuse yourself at an opportune moment and just say I'll be back in a minute. Everyone doesn't need to know where you are going and what you are doing.

Avoid slang terms.

People know that foreigners sometimes speak a little strangely and use unconventional words occasionally.

Use common sense propriety and nobody will think any the less of you.

Comment: Exactly.  If I know where the restroom is, I simply say "I'll be right back" on my way to the door, and everyone understands.

Comment: When I ask for the facilities I do not shout it out, but at times you need to get directions out of the room you are. If you know how to ask in the local polite version, you can do so much less observed.

Answer (score 6):

I'm Australian. We like directness. Among friends we can be very blunt: "Where's the dunny?"

Among foreigners we tone it down to merely informational and if we think the other person might be offended we use a more discreet low tone and start with a warning about impending directness: "I don't know the local polite form so I'm going to be direct. Where is the toilet, men's room or whatever you call it here?"

You won't offend and you will get *two* important pieces of information.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that is the kind of information I was looking for.

Comment: Aussies. Always fun. Take it easy =D

Comment: An observation to keep you out of trouble down under: the closer you are with someone the more direct you can be. If people exchange appalling insults but keep smiling this means they are lifelong friends. It does *not* mean you can speak to them like this. Stick with direct. Flat out rude is a privilege reserved for long-time friends.

Answer (score 5):

Just indicate that you need to wash your hands.  That usually gets the idea across in polite society.

Comment: "The toilet is occupied. Just use the kitchen sink."

Comment: @Anko I know some people who wouldn't mind "using" the kitchen sink..

Comment: I thought, "this urinal is rather high."  Then I woke up.

Comment: In the netherlands they will show you the kitchen sink or fountain when you ask to 'wash your hands'. Can you add where you are from, that might help me with where to use it.

Comment: @Willeke "fountain" is not a correct translation for "fonteintje", I think.

Comment: @SQB wait so that means... oh no...

Comment: It is just a place to wash your hands, not sure what the English word is.

Comment: I think the phrase "need to wash one's hands" as a euphemism for needing the toilet is a British thing (or at least, not U.S.).

Comment: @Willeke The proper translation for a ["fonteintje"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=fonteintje) is "hand basin" (which is a small wash basin).

Comment: In the US, at least, rather than "hand basin," we'd say *sink.* Or, *kitchen sink,* *bathroom sink* (never *restroom sink*), etc. Some people might say *basin* or *wash basin,* but not often, at least where I'm from.

Answer (score 3):

It pretty much depends on which part of the world you are in.

Your choice of words could be limited by their command of English and their history (e.g. an American colony in the following example).

I remember arriving to Ninoy Aquino International Airport in Manila, and asking to a member of the airport crew where could I go to the loo, wc, gents, bathroom...and so on, until I hit on the toilet word. "oh, you want to go to the toilet..."

Actually asking for the toilets is not the difficult part, as the habit is pretty universal. The tricky part is the variations in cultures and habits about the cleaning part...

Answer (score 2):

The joys of English mean there's no actual *word* as such for the room in question. Everything is a euphemism.

> a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.

Which means that just about anything on the list is valid.

Americans seem to like *Restroom* and *Bathroom*. In the rest of the English speaking world you're likely to be sent to the wrong place in either case as they might think you want a rest or a bath.

In England, in quiet mixed company a question of *Where's the um..?* will usually get you to the right place. *Toilet*, *lavatory* or *loo* are quite acceptable. *Little boys room* (if gender appropriate) also quite acceptable in a social setting though might raise a laugh. *John*, *Head*, *Karzi*, *Bog*, *Lav* are situational and you'll rarely be in the situation. *Crapper* is actually well understood but almost never used and if you're among people you know you could just stand up and state that you need to take a *slash*, which way should you go.

Comment: Never heard of a *slash*, in the U.S.

Comment: @LarsH it's UK slang, possibly regional certainly common around me growing up

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, a coworker (new at that time) mentioned to me in a matter-of-fact way that he intends to visit the boys' corner.
I was confused and asked him what he meant, to which he translated it as "toilet". I was amused with the realisation!
It may not be a polite way of inquiring with the other gender, though!

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. This is more of an anecdote than an answer and maybe should rather be a comment?! How does it help the OP?

Comment: Apologies, if that us not formatted well enough for an answer. My initial intention was to add it as a comment, but my inexistent reputation forbade it.

Comment: I see that you are unable to comment yet, in that case don't worry, this answer will be taken care of and you are still very welcome to participate here :) If you want to gain reputation quickly, have a look to our [bounty questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), which are especially plentiful this month, a good answer will quickly gain you rep here.

Comment: While not a formal answer, I do appreciate the information.